# Как использовать jQuery File Upload?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте.

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, что такое jQuery File Upload. Не имею в виду функциональность, a как подключить к проекту. И нужно ли дополнительно писать код?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

1. Все  описано в доке, это клиентская библиотека, на серверной стороне подключайте обрабатывая данные от http сервера (в доках все расписано).
2. Да, код писать придется.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806075/File-Upload-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASP-NET-Web-API